# Как вывести этот массив в одну строку?

Tags: python, массивы, list

```
[('1. ', 'авокадо'), ('2. ', 'банан'), ('3. ', 'Молоко'), ('4. ', 'Орехи'), ('5. ', 'тридцать пять')
```

Нужно преобразовать этот массив в переменную через "\n"

Чтобы вышло это:

```
1. авокадо
2. банан
3. Молоко 
4. Орехи
5. тридцать пять
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужна новая переменная то:

```
data = [('1. ', 'авокадо'), ('2. ', 'банан'), ('3. ', 'Молоко'), ('4. ', 'Орехи'), ('5. ', 'тридцать пять')]
result = "\n".join([f"{item[0]}{item[1]}" for item in data])
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```py
lst = [('1. ', 'авокадо'), ('2. ', 'банан'), ('3. ', 'Молоко'), ('4. ', 'Орехи'), ('5. ', 'тридцать пять')]
print(*map(''.join, lst), sep='\n')
```

Если в переменную, то видимо так:

```
result = '\n'.join(map(''.join, lst))
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вывести каждый кортеж на новой строке можно использовать такой код:

```
my_list = [('1. ', 'авокадо'), ('2. ', 'банан'), ('3. ', 'Молоко'), ('4. ', 'Орехи'), ('5. ', 'тридцать пять')]

for key, value in my_list:
    print(key, value)
```

А чтобы вывести все в одну строку можно использовать такой код:

```
my_list = [('1. ', 'авокадо'), ('2. ', 'банан'), ('3. ', 'Молоко'), ('4. ', 'Орехи'), ('5. ', 'тридцать пять')]

for key, value in my_list:
    print(key, value, end=" ")
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!